# Pre-pre production repository?

Tags: svn

I'm working with a customer that has set up a repository for me to work on. I work on my computer, and then commit.

I'd like to know how can I have something like a pre-pre production; that way, I can have someone help me with coding. The commits of my assistant would go to me, and then, after checking, I would commit to the client's repository. Is this possible? And if so, how? The repository uses SVN.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using dev branches. Then you can commit, review, and then merge into trunk or another branch.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The problem is that the customer doesn't want any more branches, is it possible to have these branches at my local only, and then commit them to trunk?

Comment: @luqita: With SVN local not-committed branches are not possible. With Git they are. Why the hell the customer care about a number of branches?

Answer (score 0):

1. Separate SVN-repo for your team. Reviewed revisions are exported as patches, later - imported into customer repo
2. Use another SCM (DVCS only, AFAICK), as bridge between your local SVN and customer SVN repo (or just use DVCS with SVN support) - I'll suggest Mercurial with hgsubversion